# Not able to print a generic msg using rspec with generic method in ruby cucumber

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

Using cucumber site-prism.I'm navigating to a page and wants to check all elements present on that page.I used this code but not able to print this generic message.

"@sign_in" is the object of the class where i have defined all sign in elements
"table" contains all the elements name

```
table.hashes.each do |link|
 expect(@sign_in.send(link[:Login_elements])).to be_truthy ,  "link[:Login_elements]) is not present"
end
```

Comment: What output do you get?  What output do you want to get?

Comment: For failing scenario i get "Unable to find css", the output i want is the "link[:Login_elements]) is not present ". Which is executed only when expectation fails.

Comment: Please see the [minimum, verifiable, and complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) guide. You can't expect people to solve your problem if you don't show the steps you've taken thus far, including all relevant code.

Comment: Looks like you're getting an `Capybara::ElementNotFound` exception from `@sign_in.send(link[:Login_elements])`?

Answer (score 0):

The methods you are calling via `send` return the element or raise an exception if the element isn't on the page which isn't going to work with be_truthy. Instead you need to use the boolean has_xxx? methods site-prism provides (or you could use the raise_error matcher with a block of code)

```
table.hashes.each do |link|
  expect(@sign_in.send("has_#{link[:Login_elements]}?")).to be_truthy , "link[:Login_elements]) is not present"
end
```